# Gronwall's inequality

Tags: statistics, inequality, nonparametric-statistics

I am reading the [article](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ethanh-mai.pham-ngoc/HoangPhamRivoirardTran.pdf).
I am getting stuck with the first proof proposition 4 on page 32.
To be more specific, they understood the reason why they obtained $F(x) \le \frac{2K}{1-\frac{2R\epsilon}{\alpha}}+\frac{2CR}{\alpha -2R\epsilon}\int_{x}^{\epsilon}F(y) dy$.

Then, they choose $\epsilon$ such that $0 <\epsilon < \frac{\alpha}{2R}$ and they said that "Applying Gronwall's inequality to this inequality, we obtain

$F(x) \le \frac{K}{1-\frac{2R\epsilon}{\alpha}} \exp\left(\frac{2CR\epsilon}{\alpha - 2R\epsilon}\right)$ where $ x \in [0;\epsilon].$

I don't know which version of Gronwall's inequality did they use? Thank you for reading my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Gronwall do you know? And what does it yield to you?

Comment: There are a lot of versions of Gronwall inequality 
https://rgmia.org/papers/monographs/standard.pdf
but the problem is that they usually take the integral between ... to {y}
In my problem, the integral is between x to epsilon